# What will be selector for multi class HTML element in CSS or JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to select exactly this element with use CSS selectors or JQuery (it can be the same if possible in CSS).

```
<div class="product-panel prices-list-panel"></div>
```

How can I select elements with `'.product-panel'` AND `'.prices-list-panel'`?

Comment: Note: Answers are not shown in date posted order. Hover over the "answered" date to see the actual date/time posted.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
.product-panel.prices-list-panel{....}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the selectors.

```
$(.product-panel.prices-list-panel')
```

or in css do the same:

```
.product-panel.prices-list-panel{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery

```
$('div.product-panel.prices-list-panel')
```

and in css

```
div.product-panel.prices-list-panel{ 
    //style
}
```

REF : https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the class names

```
.product-panel.prices-list-panel {
   ...
}
```

or also via attribute selector

```
[class="product-panel"][class="prices-list-panel"] { 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[Multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**:

```
$('.product-panel.prices-list-panel')
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You can just stack elements

so in your case

```
div.product-panel.prices-list-panel {
}
```

Would ensure it's only on elements with these two classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
$('.product-panel.prices-list-panel')
```

Just join your class name.

and for **css**:

```
.product-panel.prices-list-panel {

//do stuff here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If classes are on same element as in your case then select them by this way

```
.product-panel.prices-list-panel
```

means no space between the selectors.

Similarly you can do with jQuery like

```
$('.product-panel.prices-list-panel')
```